# What's the wrong with the given python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def myfunc(text, num):
    while num > 0:
        print(text)
     num = num - 1

myfunc('Hello', 4)
```

Comment: why this code run infinitely

Comment: Is `num = num - 1` supposed to be inside the loop?

Comment: the indentation

Comment: `num` doesn't change in the loop.

Comment: See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

num isn't properly indented.

Try:

```
def myfunc(text, num):
    while num > 0:
        print(text)
        num = num - 1

myfunc('Hello', 4)
```

Comment: why num is  not indented I cant undersatnd logic behind this